# gatsby custom source plugin - need help to get all the data

Tags: node.js, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am working on my first custom source plugin for gatsby, but I am stuck now..

Its working so far that I get the data I need create node, but not for all the data.

the response i get from the api looks like this

```
{
    "section1": {
        "date": "...",
        "moreinformartion": "...",
    },
    "section2": [
        {
            "sub1": {
                "information": "..."
            }
        },
        {
            "sub2": {
                "information": "..."
            }
        },
        {
            "sub2": {
                "information": "..."
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But with all the tutorials out there, I was "only" able  to get a node for every `sub` in `section2`

```
result.data.roster.forEach(data => {
    
            const node = {
                ...data,
                id: createNodeId(`KILL-setup-${data.character.name}`),
                internal: {
                    type: 'KILLSetup',
                    contentDigest: createContentDigest(data)
                }
            };
            actions.createNode(node);
        });
```

How can I get 1 node, with all the data inside?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do we need the second codeblock?

Comment: the second codeblock is how I got 1 node for each sub-section in `section2`. but i need the data from `section1` and dont know how to do that..
I tried some more in the meantime and got 1 single node, with all data in it, but then i dont know how to query the data, cause infact, in the real result every `sub1` `sub2` etc is called the same.. to be more precise, my goal ist do get everything from [this](https://raider.io/api/v1/guilds/boss-kill?region=eu&realm=aegwynn&guild=zero&raid=nyalotha-the-waking-city&boss=vexiona&difficulty=mythic) accessable through my graphql